# Como imprimir conteúdo html de uma div quando guardo a informação na base de dados?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boa noite,

Tenho um sistema de controlo de entradas e saídas de reparações informáticas o que pretendo e que quando guardo a informaçao na base de dados logo de seguida me dei-a para imprimir o conteúdo html de uma div onde ira constar os dados guardados.

Neste caso quero que caso seja guardado com sucesso me abra a opcao para imprimir o conteúdo da div.

```
<script> 
$(document).on("click", "#novo", function(e) { 
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    var postData = $("#form_novo").serialize();
    var cliente = $("#cliente").val();
    var avaria = $("#avaria").val();
    if(cliente === '' || avaria === ''){
        toastr.error('Preencha os campos obrigatórios!', 'Campos');
    }else{
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "modulos/reparacoes/guardar.php",
            data: postData,
            cache: true
        }).done(function(msg) {
            toastr.success('Dados guardados com sucesso!', 'Reparações');
        }).fail(function(data) {
            toastr.error('Ocorreu um erro!', 'Erro');
        });
    }
});    
</script>
```

Comment: Olá, já tem a opção criada para imprimir conteudo?

Comment: Não e isso que gostaria de fazer

Comment: O que quer dizer com o imprimir? Popular campos? Enviar para a impressora?

Comment: Sim mal grave caso seja guardado com sucesso imprima os campos em que vou colocar num html

Comment: Já tem esse html feito? se sim insira na pergunta com a informação que quer popular esses campos. Também vais ser necessário ter uma resposta do servidor em JSON (pelo menos seria assim que eu faria).

Comment: Não tenho o html feito ainda so preciso de saber como faço para imprimir depois do done do javascript abra a opção para imprimir esse html que vai ficar numa div

Comment: OK. Tentei simplificar o processo. Se continuar a ter questões pergunte que vou alterando a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Se a gravação for com sucesso deverá devolver do servidor todos os dados que pretende em JSON.

EXEMPLO.:
{NOME:'teste',CONTACTO:'123'}
Em php para devolver este JSON
print_r(json_encode (array('NOME'=>'teste','TELEFONE'=>'123')));

Na função que já tem em AJAX o done deverá por visível a opção de imprimir. (Pode colocar visível se já existir ou então pode criar o botão/imagem)
E deve fazer um código parecido a.:

```
  msg=JSON.parse(msg); //a variável msg é a variável que recebe no done
  //Vamos supor que essa opção tem o ID igual a ImprimirDados.
  $('#ImprimirDados').on('click',function(){ 
     for (var dados in msg){
        //dados tem o índex JSON exemplo NOME
        //msg[dados] tem o valor JSON exemplo teste
        //Se os índex tiverem os mesmo nomes dos campos
        $('#'+dados).val(msg[dados]);
     }
 });
```